# How to programatically group lap times into teams to minimize difference?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given the following (arbitrary) lap times:

```
John: 47.20
Mark: 51.14
Shellie: 49.95
Scott: 48.80
Jack: 46.60
Cheryl: 52.70
Martin: 57.65
Karl: 55.45
Yong: 52.30
Lynetta: 59.90
Sueann: 49.24
Tempie: 47.88
Mack: 51.11
Kecia: 53.20
Jayson: 48.90
Sanjuanita: 45.90
Rosita: 54.43
Lyndia: 52.38
Deloris: 49.90
Sophie: 44.31
Fleta: 58.12
Tai: 61.23
Cassaundra: 49.38 
Oren: 48.39
```

We're doing a go-kart endurance race, and the idea, rather than allowing team picking is to write a tool to process the initial qualifying times and then spit out the closest-matched groupings.

My initial investigation makes me feel like this is a clique graphing type situation, but having never played with graphing algorithms I feel rather out of my depth.

What would be the fastest/simplest method of generating groups of 3 people with the closest overall average lap time, so as to remove overall advantage/difference between them?

Is this something I can use networkx to achieve, and if so, how would I best define the graph given the dataset above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're faced with a problem like this, one approach is always to leverage randomness.

While other folks say they *think* X or Y should work, I *know* my algorithm will converge to at least a local maxima. If you can show that any state space can be reached from any other via pairwise swapping (a property that is true for, say, the Travelling Salesperson Problem), then the algorithm will find the global optimum (given time).

Further, the algorithm attempts to minimize the standard deviation of the average times across the groups, so it provides a natural metric of how good an answer you're getting: Even if the result is non-exact, getting a standard deviation of 0.058 is probably more than close enough for your purposes.

Put another way: there may be an exact solution, but a randomized solution is usually easy to imagine, doesn't take long to code, can converge nicely, and is able to produce acceptable answers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import copy
import random

data = [
  (47.20,"John"),
  (51.14,"Mark"),
  (49.95,"Shellie"),
  (48.80,"Scott"),
  (46.60,"Jack"),
  (52.70,"Cheryl"),
  (57.65,"Martin"),
  (55.45,"Karl"),
  (52.30,"Yong"),
  (59.90,"Lynetta"),
  (49.24,"Sueann"),
  (47.88,"Tempie"),
  (51.11,"Mack"),
  (53.20,"Kecia"),
  (48.90,"Jayson"),
  (45.90,"Sanjuanita"),
  (54.43,"Rosita"),
  (52.38,"Lyndia"),
  (49.90,"Deloris"),
  (44.31,"Sophie"),
  (58.12,"Fleta"),
  (61.23,"Tai"),
  (49.38 ,"Cassaundra"),
  (48.39,"Oren")
]

#Divide into initial groupings
NUM_GROUPS = 8
groups = []
for x in range(NUM_GROUPS): #Number of groups desired
  groups.append(data[x*len(data)//NUM_GROUPS:(x+1)*len(data)//NUM_GROUPS])

#Ensure all groups have the same number of members
assert all(len(groups[0])==len(x) for x in groups)

#Get average time of a single group
def FitnessGroup(group): 
  return np.average([x[0] for x in group])

#Get standard deviation of all groups' average times
def Fitness(groups):
  avgtimes = [FitnessGroup(x) for x in groups] #Get all average times
  return np.std(avgtimes) #Return standard deviation of average times

#Initially, the best grouping is just the data
bestgroups  = copy.deepcopy(groups)
bestfitness = Fitness(groups)

#Generate mutations of the best grouping by swapping two randomly chosen members
#between their groups
for x in range(10000): #Run a large number of times
  groups = copy.deepcopy(bestgroups)       #Always start from the best grouping
  g1 = random.randint(0,len(groups)-1)     #Choose a random group A
  g2 = random.randint(0,len(groups)-1)     #Choose a random group B
  m1 = random.randint(0,len(groups[g1])-1) #Choose a random member from group A
  m2 = random.randint(0,len(groups[g2])-1) #Choose a random member from group B
  groups[g1][m1], groups[g2][m2] = groups[g2][m2], groups[g1][m1] #Swap 'em
  fitness = Fitness(groups)                #Calculate fitness of new grouping
  if fitness<bestfitness:                  #Is it a better fitness?
    bestfitness = fitness                  #Save fitness
    bestgroups  = copy.deepcopy(groups)    #Save grouping

#Print the results
for g in bestgroups:
  for m in g:
    print("{0:15}".format(m[1]), end='') 
  print("{0:15.3f}".format(FitnessGroup(g)), end='')
  print("")
print("Standard deviation of teams: {0:.3f}".format(bestfitness))
```

Running this a couple of times gives a standard deviation of 0.058:

```
Cheryl         Kecia          Oren                    51.430
Tempie         Mark           Karl                    51.490
Fleta          Deloris        Jack                    51.540
Lynetta        Scott          Sanjuanita              51.533
Mack           Rosita         Sueann                  51.593
Shellie        Lyndia         Yong                    51.543
Jayson         Sophie         Tai                     51.480
Martin         Cassaundra     John                    51.410
Standard deviation of teams: 0.058
```

Comment: You sir, have gone above and beyond! Your algorithm is *precisely* what I was looking for, and the std deviation is way better than anything I expected to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: No.  Suppose that the data are normally distributed.  Then picking 8 groupings will, indeed, give you 8 groups, where 8 groups do not exist in the data.  Indeed, suppose that one wants 3 groups, but 4 groups actually exist.  This algorithm will arbitrarily lump two of those groups together.  Maybe it will lump the top two groups together, where the smart thing to do to separate teams would be to lump the bottom two groups together.  You could probably use cross-validation on this algorithm to pick the best number of groups, but what if the number of groups it picks isn't the number you want?

Comment: @Scott: The user specifies the number of groups, as constrained by the number and size of the races they want to run (read OP's post: "generating groups of 3 people with the closest overall average lap time"). The algorithm does not pick the number of groups, it merely finds the best groupings given the user-specified number. Your criticism is correct, but for a different problem.

Comment: @Scott: [jwimberley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44848352/752843) has a lucid explanation of what OP is after: "The idea is to take the N people and group them into N/3 teams, making the average times of the N/3 teams [rather than the 3 people within each team as I mistakenly interpreted] as close as possible."

Comment: Ooo!  This is a much more interesting problem than I had originally read it to be.  I guess I'm a jaded stackexchange-question-reader.  :)  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, just sort the list of times and group the first three, next three, up through the top three.

*EDIT: I didn't understand correctly*

So, the idea is to take the N people and group them into N/3 teams, making the average times N/3 teams [rather than the 3 people within each team as I mistakenly interpreted] as close as possible. In this case, I think you could still start by sorting the N drivers in decreasing order of times. Then, initialize an empty list of N/3 teams. Then for each driver in decreasing order of lap time, assign them to the team with the smallest current total lap time (or one of these teams, in case of ties). This is a variant of a simple bin packing algorithm.

Here is a simple Python implementation:

```
times = [47.20, 51.14, 49.95, 48.80, 46.60, 52.70, 57.65, 55.45, 52.30, 59.90, 49.24, 47.88, 51.11, 53.20, 48.90, 45.90, 54.43, 52.38, 49.90, 44.31, 58.12, 61.23, 49.38, 48.39]

Nteams = len(times)/3
team_times = [0] * Nteams
team_members = [[]] * Nteams

times = sorted(times,reverse=True)
for m in range(len(times)):
    i = team_times.index(min(team_times))
    team_times[i] += times[m]
    team_members[i] = team_members[i] + [m]

for i in range(len(team_times)):
    print(str(team_members[i]) + ": avg time " + str(round(team_times[i]/3,3)))
```

whose output is

```
[0, 15, 23]: avg time 51.593
[1, 14, 22]: avg time 51.727
[2, 13, 21]: avg time 51.54
[3, 12, 20]: avg time 51.6
[4, 11, 19]: avg time 51.48
[5, 10, 18]: avg time 51.32
[6, 9, 17]: avg time 51.433
[7, 8, 16]: avg time 51.327
```

(Note that the team members numbers refer to them in descending order of lap time, starting from 0, rather than to their original ordering).

One issue with this is that if the times varied dramatically, there is no hard restriction to make the number of players on each team exactly 3. However, for your purposes, maybe that's OK, if it makes the relay close, and its probably a rare occurrence when the spread in times is much less than the average time.

*EDIT*
If you do just want 3 players on each team, in all cases, then the code can be trivially modified to at each step find the team with the least total lap time that doesn't already have three assigned players. This requires a small modification in the main code block:

```
times = sorted(times,reverse=True)
for m in range(len(times)):
    idx = -1
    for i in range(Nteams):
        if len(team_members[i]) < 3:
            if (idx == -1) or (team_times[i] < team_times[idx]):
                idx = i
    team_times[idx] += times[m]
    team_members[idx] = team_members[idx] + [m]
```

For the example problem in the question, the above solution is of course identical, because it did not try to fit more or less than 3 players per team.

Comment: This wouldn't result in closely matched teams though...

Take the following example:

1
2
3
4

The grouping should result in 2 groups:
3+2
4+1

Comment: I assumed that when you said groups of three people with the closet average lap time, you meant closet *within* these groups of three people, because 3 people would be racing each other at a time. But did you mean closest average lap time between the groups? I guess that's why you call them teams...

Comment: Thanks @noirsette for pointing out my error; I have edited the answer to correctly address the question.

Comment: The solution given by your answer is suboptimal. Your standard deviation of the average times of the groups is 0.1317: I find 0.058 in my answer. (Which is not to say that your method's a poor solution, just that it's non-exact and we don't know the bound on the error.)

Comment: @Richard Yes, yours is empirically superior, and a pretty neat solution! Though I'd argue mine has the small benefit of simplicity.

Comment: @jwimberley: True that: it's a nice idea, though I wonder if you get similar results and simplicity once JaredGoguen's criticism that you can end up with unequally-sized teams is taken into account?

Comment: @Richard Taking that into account only requires a small change in the code, that replaces the `min` function with an explicit search for the minimum under the condition that the team isn't already full. For the given problem the solution is identical.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm appears to work pretty well. It takes the fastest and slowest people remaining and then finds the person in the middle so that the group average is closest to the global average. Since the extreme values are being used up first, the averages at the end shouldn't be that far off despite the limited selection pool.

```
from bisect import bisect

times = sorted([47.20, 51.14, 49.95, 48.80, 46.60, 52.70, 57.65, 55.45, 52.30, 59.90, 49.24, 47.88, 51.11, 53.20, 48.90, 45.90, 54.43, 52.38, 49.90, 44.31, 58.12, 61.23, 49.38, 48.39])
average = lambda c: sum(c)/len(c)

groups = []
average_time = average(times)

while times:
    group = [times.pop(0), times.pop()]

    # target value for the third person for best average
    target = average_time * 3 - sum(group)
    index = min(bisect(times, target), len(times) - 1)

    # adjust if the left value is better than the right
    if index and abs(target - times[index-1]) < abs(target - times[index]):
        index -= 1

    group.append(times.pop(index))
    groups.append(group)

# [44.31, 61.23, 48.9]
# [45.9, 59.9, 48.8]
# [46.6, 58.12, 49.9]
# [47.2, 57.65, 49.38]
# [47.88, 55.45, 51.14]
# [48.39, 54.43, 51.11]
# [49.24, 53.2, 52.3]
# [49.95, 52.7, 52.38]
```

The sorting and the iterated binary search are both O(n log n), so the total complexity is O(n log n). Unfortunately, expanding this to larger groups might be tough.

Comment: With a standard deviation of 0.309 between the groups' average times, this does worse than both jwimberley's answer (0.132) and my own (0.058).

Comment: @Richard And? The goal was a simple algorithm that performs well enough. I wouldn't have added it, except jwimberley's algorithm isn't guaranteed to produce an valid solution so it didn't seem like a complete answer.

Comment: @Richard But good call regarding using the standard deviation as the metric. I was originally gauging it using the sum of absolute differences, which is probably a worse indicator.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Well, its trivial to modify mine to produce a valid solution, by capping off teams once they have three members.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: I hadn't noticed that problem with jwimberley's answer - good eye! Standard deviation can be a useful metric for genetic algorithms as it penalizes more heavily answers with large spreads, thereby more quickly focusing the search. Also: it's handy that numpy has a built-in command for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* would probably be to just create 3 buckets--a fast bucket, a medium bucket, and a slow bucket--and assign entries to the buckets by their qualifying times.

Then team together the slowest of the slow, the fastest of the fast, and the median or mean of the mediums. (Not sure whether median or mean is the best choice off the top of my head.) Repeat until you're out of entries.

Comment: Interesting, and definitely more efficient than what I was envisaging. I guess my key thing to remember is the outcome doesn't have to be *perfect*, so I don't need to implement an NP-complete algorithm!